# How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when calling a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

When I call the JavaScript function the control direct jump to the top of the page:

```
<!-- capture image -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

 <!-- js.ui range or slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

function capture() 
{
    $('#target').html2canvas(
    {
        onrendered: function (canvas) 
        {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        }
    });

}

$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:250,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 25,
        slide: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            capture();
        }
    });
```

i am calling the above capture(); withn the slider but the page is jump to top... pleas if let you?

Comment: how are you calling `test` ?

Comment: `html2canvas`? What's that? Also, please provide the HTML / JavaScript you're using to call `test()`.

Comment: look up `e.preventDefault`

Comment: basically im calling capture() function withn test() function?

Comment: And what's calling test()?

Comment: e.preventDefault its working but im adding the value to #img_val element .... this "html2canvas" creat binary value (image) for "target" div

Comment: test(); is a function which is latter im caling somewhere .... simple that im calling the capture(); withen another JavaScript function? i want the control to be there ?

Comment: shoaib, please be a little more specific. There's a load of `html2canvas` libraries out there. Add a link to the library you're using, in your question. Also, like I said before, please add the HTML / JavaScript that's calling `test()` in your question.

Comment: i am calling the capture() with the slider it all OK but the page is jump to the top?

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false` in your `onclick` callback :

```
<a href='#' onclick='test(); return false;'>call test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the browser is jumping to the top of the page I'm guessing you are calling `test` from an event handler on a link with `href="#"`. The browser's default action for following a link to `"#"` is to jump to the top of the page.

You need to tell the browser that, once your handler has run, it should not proceed with its default action.

DOM event handlers typically accept an [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) as the first argument. You can call its `preventDefault` method to do that:

```
$('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  test();
});
```

Comment: This answer actually explains why `preventDefault` should work. +1

Comment: there is something wrong with capture();? if i add the preventDefault(); to the capture(); then the value did not add to #img_val element?

Comment: OK - I'm not sure how the slider control works, so it's possible the `preventDefault` doesn't work here. I will edit out that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just return false or use event.preventDefault() on click event

Answer (score 0):

YOU can simple replace # with javascript:;`<a href="javascript:;">call test</a>`.

When you will click, nothing will scroll on page.